# php - How do I redirect a user based on their form input?

Tags: php, forms

I want a simple form with one text box and a submit button. For example: If a user enters "foobar" into the text box and hits enter, they should be redirected to mysite.com/browse/foobar

Does anyone know how I can do this in php? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

index.php

```
header("Location: http://example.com/browse/".$_GET['q']);
```

Note: this is not good practice but it works.

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm after. But I'm concerned that it's not "good practice". Is there a better way?

Comment: look at mod_rewrite. that is what most sites use to get "clean" URLs.

Comment: A better way would be to only allow alphanumeric characters in $_GET['q'] - this can be done with $q = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", '', $_GET['q']);

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `name='q'` for the text input

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['q'] === "foobar") {
        header("Location: http://example.com/browse/foobar");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but I meant "foobar" to mean any word the user wants to enter

Comment: http://uk3.php.net/urlencode plus a tiny bit of string concatenation and you're there.